# Read a file from a class of a Jar B which is provided as maven dependency in Jar A

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have Maven Project X, in which I have added maven dependency of Y, now in jar Y  I have a static method which reads a file from a path provided. From a java class of project-X path for the file to read is supplied to static method of Y.

File to be read is in src/main/resources of project X.

I tried

```
File file = new File("abc.txt"));
String configFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

this thing works in Windows environment, but fails on linux environment.

Any leads / help on this is appreciated, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want to find a file in your resource directory the best way is to do something like that:
`File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("filename").toURI());`
By the way it has nothing to do with dependencies.

Comment: This doesn't help. When I add Jar B's dependency in Project X, and build the project X then it read jar B from .m2/repository/abc/abc/1.0/xyz.jar , now want to read a file from jar B ,file is sitting in classpath of Project X. This is my problem.

Comment: Ok, I got it what you want with maven dependencies. So your file is inside a jar file, therefore it isn't really a file. You wont be able to do any file operation with it, so why would you create a file object that represents it?
If you want to access the content of your file you can do it like this:
`InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myTextFile.txt");`
And than you can read the content from the InputStream.

Comment: No My file is in Project X, and I want to read it from Project Y . I have added project Y to maven dependency of Project X. A piece of code in project Y read a file from classpath of Project X at runtime. This is the issue.

Comment: Yes, your file is in project x therefore it is packaged in the artifact generated from project x. Probably some kind of projectx.jar. This jar goes to your local maven repository, and this is how other projects will access it. There is no way to access the source directory tree of project x from project y. But you can access the content of projectx.jar via the classloader as I wrote it.